# Add README.md to published npm package

Tags: npm

I already published a package to NPM, but forgot the README. I updated the package, tried `npm publish ./` again, but it says I can't publish on top of a published package.

So, how do I send a README to a published package?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should increment the version. Like `0.0.0` to `0.0.1`.

Just open `package.json` in your text editor, find `"version":"0.0.0"` and type in the new value.

Answer (score 1):

After incrementing the version. Like `0.0.0` to `0.0.1` in your `package.json` file

Create a `README.md` in the project root directory of your package. after writing up your read me. you can now publish your package by running the `npm publish`. that should work and should show up your readme on the npm site.